# How to remove unused css in Vuetify?

Tags: css, vuetify.js

I am using Vuetify 2 and using it with 'a la carte' option. I extract the CSS for each route, so the app only loads the necessary CSS for that view. 
What I see is that `chunk-vendors.css` contains al the CSS for Vuetify, instead of breaking them out for each view-chunk.

Is this possible to get smaller CSS files on the first load to get maximum performance? Thnx!

Comment: Did you follow this guide https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/colors#sass-color-pack ? and it work for you? I have the same problem

Comment: Yes I did follow it carefully, but it doesn't say anything about removing unused CSS

Comment: Did you have any luck with this ?

Comment: Nope, there is nothing I could find useful yet

Comment: Make sure to read through [treeshaking](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/features/treeshaking/) part of the Vuetify 2 documentation. Using **vuetify-loader** or importing components manually will help you reduce the chunk size.